# IE-11: Object doesn't support property or method 'parseInt'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

My apps front end is built in `angular js 1.4.14` and I am encountering the following error only in IE-11:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'parseInt'

Here is my Html:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Pickup time <span ng-show="pickupTimeIsRange()">range</span>:</label>
           <div class="row col-md-10">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                     <input placeholder="{{ pickupTimeIsRange() ? 'Start time' : 'Time' }}" class="form-control" ui-timepicker ng-model="info.pickup_time_start">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" ng-show="pickupTimeIsRange()">
                     <input placeholder="End time" class="col-md-4 form-control" ui-timepicker ng-model="info.pickup_time_end">
                </div>
           </div>
</div>
```

And here is my js code:

```
info.pickup_time_start = getTime('start');
info.pickup_time_end = pickupTimeIsRange() ? getTime('end') : null;

function getTime(time) {
   return !_.has(info.pickup_time, time) || _.isEmpty(info.pickup_time[time])
        ? null
        : moment(info.pickup_time[time], 'HH:mm');
}
```

Now, what is going wrong here? My code is compiled when the app is run so the above error occurs in `lib.js` file which is a compiled js code file from which I don't know where actually `Number.parseInt` is being used. is there any way to force global `parseInt` to be used? Or is there any way I can figure out where exactly `Number.parseInt` is being used?
I know that much that this error pops up when the above code runs, like when `ui-timepicker` is executed, when I try to select a time. So `ui-timepicker` is using `Number.parseInt` somewhere in the code which I am unable to figure out where exactly.

**EDIT**

By the way, it is working fine on my local with the same browser, same code, and same OS. That is very strange that on the live instance it doesn't work! Why is that?

Comment: Some code somewhere is very likely calling `Number.parseInt` which doesn't exists in IE11. There is only the global `parseInt` there. The two work exactly the same so for IE only it can be polyfilled as `Number.parseInt = parseInt` (with an appropriate guard). However, fundamentally it seems that you have some code that is not IE11 compliant and patching *this* might be a temporary solution. The code isn't present in what you've shown, so you have to track down where it is and tackle it then.

Comment: @VLAZ the error in the brower tells me it is in lib.js file but that is framework file, so how can I know which part of my code is triggering it?

Comment: By creating a [mcve] and by using a debugger

Comment: Which framework do you use? Have you used some codes which are not compatible with IE and then polyfilled them? You can also check if there're some files not loading when the website runs on server. There's nothing related with `parseInt` in the code you providing and we can't reproduce the issue through it. I suggest that you can provide a code snippet which can **reproduce** the issue so that we can see how to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I got to the issue. In my case `jquery` `timepicker` was being problematic. I updated it to the latest version available and issue is gone.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `parseInt` is used on line 841, https://github.com/wvega/timepicker/blob/master/jquery.timepicker.js

If you want to keep the older version you can update the lib and save it to your source files list